# Soft Key Board changing location of ImageView

Tags: android, xml

i want the Image View view to have a fixed position at the bottom of the screen and not change when the keyboard shows up. but this is not working though the image view is not inside the scroll view.

below is the XML:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff1f1f1"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/slds"
            >

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            android:layout_below="@+id/slds"
            android:fillViewport="true">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:background="#1fffffff"
                    android:text="@string/Version_number"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textColor="#ff7c7c7c"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/DB_Name"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
                    android:ems="15"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:hint="@string/username"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000">
                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
                    android:ems="15"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to make it work by editing the XML like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/MainActivyRelativeLayout"
    android:background="#fff1f1f1"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/slds"
        >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrll"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:id="@+id/gv_logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Developed By"
            android:layout_below="@id/gv_logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slds"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrll">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                >


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:background="#1fffffff"
                android:text="@string/Version_number"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="#ff7c7c7c"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/DB_Name"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
                android:ems="15"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:hint="@string/username"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000">
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
                android:ems="15"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffff3300"
                    android:onClick="login"
                    android:text="@string/Login"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:windowBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>




            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest file, put this whre your activity is:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.ProizvodiMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ProizvodiMain" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

For editText not apearing you add

```
editText.bringInFront();
editText.invalidate();
```

Comment: editText.bringToFront(); and after that
                    editText.invalidate();